# Method of ordering groups in ggplot line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot with the following code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(vars = factor(vars, levels = reord)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = EI1, y = vars, group = groups)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=groups)) + 
    geom_point() +
    xlab("EI1 (Expected Influence with Neighbor)") +
    ylab("Variables")
```

The result is:

[image]

While the ei1_other group is in descending order on x, the ei1_gun points are ordered by variables.  I would like both groups to follow the same order, such that ei1_gun and ei1_other both start at Drugs and then descend in order of the variables, rather than descending by order of x values.

Comment: Please could you share your `df` ? There are plenty of options to solve your issue but without data we can not reproduce your issue.

Comment: I apologize.  I am fairly new to SO and I didn't think to add some sample data.  Thank you for letting me know and I will do that next time.  @stefan provided the solution below.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the order by which `geom_line` connects the points is determined by the value on the x-axis. To solve this issue simply swap `x` and `y` and make use of `coord_flip`.

As no sample dataset was provided I use an example dataset based on `mtcars` to illustrate the issue and the solution. In my example data `make` is your `vars`, `value` your `EI1` and `name` your `groups`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

example_data <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(make = row.names(.)) %>%
  select(make, hp, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(make = fct_reorder(make, hp)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-make)
```

Mapping `make` on `x` and `value` on `y` results in an unordered line plot as in you example. The reason is that the order by which the points get connected is determined by `value`:

```r
example_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = make, color = name, group = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  xlab("EI1 (Expected Influence with Neighbor)") +
  ylab("Variables")
```

[image]

In contrast, swapping `x` and `y`, i.e. mapping `make` on `x` and `value` on `y`, and making use of `coord_flip` gives a nice ordererd line plot as the order by which the points get connected is now determined by `make` (of course we also have to swap `xlab` and `ylab`):

```r
example_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = make, y = value, color = name, group = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("EI1 (Expected Influence with Neighbor)") +
  xlab("Variables")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan.  This got me 99% of the way there.  I just had to add back in the mutate line,     ```mutate(vars = factor(vars, levels = reord))```                           and it got me all the way there.  I apologize about not providing code.  I am fairly new to SO and I appreciate the advice and effort.